# How to set the default namespace in projects using project.json (.xproj)

Tags: project, asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json

In a standard `.csproj` you could go into properties and set the default namespace. How can this be achieved in a `.xproj` project using `project.json`?

Comment: AFAIK this can't be done with a project.json. You can do it with an xproj the same way you used to do it with a csproj though. Right click it in Visual Studio, and on the Application tab, change the `Default namespace`.

Comment: Add that as an answer, so I can mark it so.

Comment: you can do it via project.json, see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK this can't be done with a project.json. You can do it with an xproj the same way you used to do it with a csproj though. Right click it in Visual Studio, and on the Application tab, change the `Default namespace`.

Answer (score 43):

With ASP.NET Core 1.0.1, you can set your default namespace in the `project.json` file as follows:

```json
"tooling": {
   "defaultNamespace": "Your.Name.Space"
}
```

The [yeoman ASP.NET generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet) will respect this `defaultNamespace` when generating new classes.

For the new Visual Studio 2017 `csproj` tooling, you can add the following XML to change your default namespace (up in the top level `<PropertyGroup>` [reference](https://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/#what-to-keep)):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  ...
  <RootNamespace>My.Root.Namespace</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is only necessary if your .csproj filename does not match your intended root namespace for the project.

Comment: Where is the "tooling" element supposed to go in `project.json`?

Comment: It goes into the root of project json, so on the same level as dependencies.

Comment: I can't find the project.json file within my mvc project

Comment: @muhammadtayyab that's because all the new tooling from Microsoft ditched the project.json in favor of csproj files - so read the last part of my post to figure out what to do :)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking for the same in .Net Core we only have .csproj file